# Flexlisder images to slide and caption to fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I wanted to ask if that is possible with flexslider. I want to create a caption on the left that will fade and images would slide on the right. I heard that it would require two flexsliders but I really would like to avoid that. What do you think?

[image: Captions on the left fading with controller makes image slide on the right]

Answer (score 1):

You could give the caption/pagination outer DIV an absolute position and a minus left margin (z-index set at 2000 or something so it's always on top).

Flexslider has a callback method that would allow you to fade the caption when the slider moves. Click on the advanced tab at http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/ and there's a load of callback examples.